# Windows Small Business Server 2008 and Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange-2010

Is there going to be a release of SBS 2008 that includes Exchange 2010? I want to take this into consideration as I might purchase SBS for the premium edition to get Sql Server at a much more cost effective rate but it feels like I would be getting shorted if I purchase SBS 2008 and receive Exchange 2007 since it is now outdated to 2010.

Comment: 11K views and 1 upvote, awesome :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has been announced that I am aware of.  From the SBS FAQ (http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/faq.aspx):

> Q.  Will there be a next version of
>   Windows Small Business Server (SBS)?
>   When will Microsoft release it?
>
> A.  Windows Small Business Server 2008
>   is an important part of the Windows
>   Server family, and we are fully
>   committed to expanding the
>   capabilities of this solution to meet
>   the needs of our SMB customers.  In
>   fact, we are currently hard at work
>   building the next version of Windows
>   SBS. We don’t have any additional
>   details to share at this point about
>   release schedules, and such.

Windows Server 2008 R2 has also released since SBS2008, and I have to imagine the Product Team is aware of these two major releases :) (I have absolutely no insider information).  If you want to make sure you don't miss out on any big updates in the next version by buying now, get it with Software Assurance so that you get the latest version once released: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/default.aspx#tab=2

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, although not on the SBS team, nor am I in a sales role

Comment: That was also something I had wondered if there was a software assurance program for this that would cover it the same way my MSDN subscription will roll up to VS 2010 and TFS 2010 sometime next year.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider Software Assurance if you are worried about the latest version of Exchange. Either way, SBS 2008 is a good all around option even with Exchange 2007.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read on the net:
even though sbs has "exchange" its not the same exchange that you get if you were to buy exchange from msft.  Because of all the hooks and stuff that sbs has to use in order for it to be able to be easily managed and interact with the SBS API.

I would imaging we will see exchange 2010 in sbs 2011 or 2012.

Answer (score 0):

SBS 2008 is an awesome solution, and the Microsoft Exchange packaged with it is extremely functional, and simple even for advanced users who might prefer powershell usage over GUI. The SBS Console in 2008 is nice, so dont listen to anyone who tells you to wait for 2010 or 2010 versions, but like the other poster said, get Software Assurance to ensure you can upgrade later on.